# SQL isnumeric validación

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

existe un campo 'USER_7' de la tabla 'WORK_ORDER', dicho campo es de tipo varchar(80). Éste almacena números.

El problema con esto, es que la tabla no la modificare con el tipo de valor correcto. Y tengo que ejecutar mis consultas sobre éstas.

Quiero sumar el campo USER_7, para ello tengo que convertirlo a tipo numérico. Si la conversión no se da por X ó Y motivo entonces que la excepción arroje un cero en la fila del error, pero que al final me sume toda la columna filtrada... con los números que sí se pudieron convertir y los ceros que fueron las filas que no se pudieron convertir.

```
                SELECT  CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(USER_7) = 1 THEN SUM(cast(USER_7 as decimal(28, 20))) else 0 end DESPERDICIO

                  FROM [SHALER].[dbo].[WORK_ORDER]

                    where BASE_ID IN (
                    'OP-00001-16',
                'OP-00007-16',
                'OP-00016-16',
                'OP-00020-16',
                'OP-00025-16',
                'OP-00030-16',
                'OP-00036-16',
                'OP-00040-16',
                'OP-00044-16',
                'OP-00047-16',
                'OP-00047-16',
                'OP-00049-16',
                'OP-00050-16',
                'OP-00055-16',
                'OP-00059-16',
                'OP-00061-16',
                'OP-00067-16',
                'OP-00069-16',
                'OP-00074-16',
                'OP-00075-16',
                'OP-00076-16'    
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu expresión `CASE` debe estar dentro de la función de agregación `SUM`:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE 
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(USER_7) = 1 THEN CAST(USER_7 as decimal(28,20))
            END) Desperdicio
FROM [SHALER].[dbo].[WORK_ORDER]
WHERE BASE_ID IN (
'OP-00001-16',
'OP-00007-16',
'OP-00016-16',
'OP-00020-16',
'OP-00025-16',
'OP-00030-16',
'OP-00036-16',
'OP-00040-16',
'OP-00044-16',
'OP-00047-16',
'OP-00047-16',
'OP-00049-16',
'OP-00050-16',
'OP-00055-16',
'OP-00059-16',
'OP-00061-16',
'OP-00067-16',
'OP-00069-16',
'OP-00074-16',
'OP-00075-16',
'OP-00076-16'    
);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias.